# Zend Studio: How do you add a new action to an existing controller via the IDE?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

If you simply add the code it doesn't do the automatic action wireup in the .zfproject.xml file. Does the IDE support a way to add additional Actions to an existing controller without manually using the command line tool?

**Adding the following information:**

I was actually looking for a built in way to update the zfproject.xml without using the zf tool feature. However, using the ZF tool I'm also running into errors. My workspace contains multiple projects in it like so:

Workspace 7

- project 1
- project 2
- project 3

When I try to run the zf tool against "project 2" to create an action it comes back with an error because it's trying to run the zf tool against the workspace root instead of the "project 2" root.

I have not found a solution to this problem - so I am still not able to use Zend Studio to create actions. I've been using Windows 7 powershell and running the zf command line interface to create actions for the time being.

Answer (score -1):

If you do it from Studio, the project file won't be updated for current versions. However, you can run ZF tool from Studio too - go to `Project/Zf Tool`. You also get some completion helping you this way.