# how to create action in Zend Studio 9.0.1

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
zf create action add Index
zf create action edit Index
zf create action delete Index
```

I am using Zend Studio 9.0.1(ZendServer-CE-php-5.3.14-5.6.0-SP4-Windows_x86), I know how to do this through zf command line in win 7. I just wonder if there is a way that I can do this manually through Zend Studio 9.0.1? Because I am using windows. I am not used to run commands. According to this post:[Zend Studio: How do you add a new action to an existing controller via the IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180234/zend-studio-how-do-you-add-a-new-action-to-an-existing-controller-via-the-ide), It seems that create actions from Studio has some problems. But it did not mention how to solve it.